# Compare with another column value

Tags: python, pandas

```
train.loc[:,'nd_mean_2021-04-15':'nd_mean_2021-08-27'] > train['q_5']
```

I get `Automatic reindexing on DataFrame vs Series comparisons is deprecated and will raise ValueError in a future version.  Do` left, right = left.align(right, axis=1, copy=False)`before e.g.`left == right` and something strange output with a lot of columns, but I did expect cell values masked with True or False for calculate sum on next step.

Comparing each columns separately works just fine

```
train['nd_mean_2021-04-15'] > train['q_5']
```

But works slowly and messy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your original solution, and two additional ways of performing this comparison you want to make.

To cut to the chase, the following option had the smallest execution time:

```py
%%timeit

sliced_df = df.loc[:, 'nd_mean_2021-04-15':'nd_mean_2021-08-27']
comparisson_df = pd.DataFrame({col: df['q_5'] for col in sliced_df.columns})
(sliced_df > comparisson_df)
# 1.46 ms ± 610 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Drawback:** it's little bit messy and requires you to create 2 new objects (`sliced_df` and `comparisson_df`)

##### Option 2: Using `DataFrame.apply` (slower but more readable)

The second option although slower than your original and the above implementations, in my opinion is the cleanest and easiest to read of them all. If you're not trying to process large amounts of data (I assume not, since you're using pandas instead of Dask or Spark that are tools more suitable for processing large volumes of data) then it's worth bringing it to the discussion table:

```py
%%timeit

df.loc[:, 'nd_mean_2021-04-15':'nd_mean_2021-08-27'].apply(lambda col: col > df['q_5'])
# 5.66 ms ± 897 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

##### Original Solution

I've also tested the performance of your original implementation and here's what I got:

```py
%%timeit

df.loc[:, 'nd_mean_2021-04-15':'nd_mean_2021-08-27'] > df['q_5']
# 2.02 ms ± 175 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**Side-Note:** If the `FutureWarning` message is bothering you, there's always the option to ignore them, adding the following code after your script imports:

```py
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=FutureWarning)
```

#### DataFrame Used for Testing

All of the above implementations used the same dataframe, that I created using the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


columns = list(
    map(
        lambda value: f'nd_mean_{value}',
        pd.date_range('2021-04-15', '2021-08-27', freq='W').to_series().dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').to_list()
    )
)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {col: np.random.randint(0, 100, 10) for col in [*columns, 'q_5']}
)
```

---

##### Screenshots

[image]